# Pushing changes from one client to all other connected clients through server?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

So I have a client:

```
public class TalkClient extends Thread
{
private int port;
private String host;
    DocCntl theDocCntl;

public TalkClient(String host, int port) throws IOException
{
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
            theDocCntl = new DocCntl(this);
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
                    System.out.println("Seeking connection...");
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int port = 5050;
    try
    {
        Thread t = new TalkClient("127.0.0.1", port);
        t.start();
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    public void pushToServer(){
        String theData = this.theDocCntl.theDoc.docTA.getText();

    }
}
```

And I have a server:

```
  public class TalkServer extends Thread
    {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
        public static DocCntl theCntl;

    public TalkServer(int port) throws IOException
    {

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
                        System.out.println("Listening for connections...");
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
        {
        int port = 5050;

        try
        {
            Thread t = new TalkServer(port);
            t.start();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the client, I have a method called pushToServer, which I want to take the String data from a textArea on the client, and then push that to all the other connected clients. But I'm not sure how to handle sending the message to each individual connected client through the sockets. I've given it some thought, and I think I need to do 3 things:

1) Create and maintain a list of connected clients(threads). In the server class itself? Or in another class?

2) On the server, have some means of 'catching' the String data from one client, and then pushing it to all the other clients. This is why(I think) I need the list of clients. If I can figure out how to catch this(maybe through the input stream?) and then iterate through the list of clients to their text areas.

3) On the client side, I need to be able to catch the string from the server.

Any help on these 3 things would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: from what i read in your code, i can say your program is for 1client/1server. You do not have a while(true) loop to accept new incoming connections

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966311/continuously-read-objects-from-an-objectinputstream-in-java?answertab=votes#tab-top